# Feed RSS problem on Wordpress, need it for Google News

Tags: rss, feed, xml, google

I need my feed to work, but i have problem with feed validator, that send me out this message

https://www.rnbjunk.com/feed/

It looks like this is a web page, not a feed. I looked for a feed associated with this page, but couldn’t find one. Please enter the address of your feed to validate.

On the feed there is line one showing

This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

Please help me! I don’t know where to ask to resolve this issue.

The page I need help with: https://www.rnbjunk.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is your CDN, Stackpath: I'd guess it's rejecting the feed validator request based on User-Agent string. If you use curl to request the feed, then it serves back `Content-Type: text/html` and

> Stackpath
>
> Sorry, you have been blocked.
>
> This website is using a security service to protect itself from online attacks. You performed an action that triggered the service and blocked your request.

There's a reference number for the block too, but you likely won't be able to get the reference number that the validator is seeing.

If you pretend to be Chrome, e.g.

```
curl --header "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36" https://www.rnbjunk.com/feed/
```

then you get the RSS feed not the error.

So I think you have to fix your StackPath configuration to be more lenient about the User-Agents for your feed URLs. There's [an article here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1061943?hl=en) that says News uses User-Agent: Googlebot-News and at first glance StackPath is blocking that too.